# It possible to create several DNS or subdomain to the virtual machine of azure?

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, virtualhost

I need to create several DNS or a subdomain to an azure virtual machine because each DNS belongs to a different company, is it possible to create several of them? Would have an additional cost? How can I create them?

Comment: Where do you need to create these DNS entries?

Comment: @CtrlDot thanks for answer, I need to create in the virtual machine of azure, to be able to have several url

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Azure stack that prevents you from creating [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) records from various DNS providers that point to your machine in Azure.

So basically you can create company1.yourdomaihn.com as a CNAME and point it to the [public ip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#public-ip-addresses) associated with your VM.  I would suggest that you point the CNAME to the "DNS Domain Label" of your public IP.

From a pricing perspective, the first 5 public IPs are free (in your subscription) after which the following [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/) applies.

Comment: Thanks, is there an updated guide to creating the CNAME?

Comment: That would depend on who you are using to host your DNS

Answer (score 0):

For now, Azure DNS is not the domian registrar, so we can't use Azure to map multiple domain names to Azure virtual machine directly.

As CtroDot said, Azure support customers to map multiple domain names to one VM. Before we try to map multiple domain names to one Azure VM, we should **buy** domain names first.
For example, if you buy domain name from **Register.com**, you can follow this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/62523?hl=en) to add CNAME.
[image][image]

Note:

We can add multiple domain names to one public IP address.

Comment: Does it work now?Please let me know if you would like further assistance.